# Highcharts write xaxis values on 2 different lines

Tags: highcharts

I am using the following for the x axis:

```
 xAxis: {
                        type: 'datetime',
                        tickInterval: 3600 * 1000, // one hour
                        tickWidth: 0,
                        gridLineWidth: 1,
                        gridLineColor: '<?php echo($gridlinecolor); ?>',
                        labels: {
                            align: 'center',
                            x: -3,
                            y: 20,
                            formatter: function() {
                                return Highcharts.dateFormat('%d-%m', this.value) + ' / '  + Highcharts.dateFormat('%l%p', this.value);
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Which gives me things like 13-02 / 4PM.

I would like to have this with a new line like
13-02
4PM

How can I achieve this?

Thanks,

John.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the html `<br/>`:

```
formatter: function() {
    return Highcharts.dateFormat('%d-%m', this.value) + '<br/>'  + Highcharts.dateFormat('%l%p', this.value);
}
```

Example fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Tg76B/).

See the section [here](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting) on HTML in Highcharts.